# How to Hook only a KeyboardFocus on Windows API

Tags: c++, c, windows, c++11, winapi

I'm searching on [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/3bstk3k5(v=vs.140)) for a Hook handler about Keyboard Focus, but didn't found.

I would like the handler for the element on focus by keyboard.

Example:

When we are on Desktop and press any key that is a first letter of a program, these program is selected.

[image: Example 1]

When we press the TAB key for navigation links, these element is selected.

[image: Example 2]

I saw the [CBTProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644977%28v=VS.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for hook a keyboard events, but is not helpful, because we can select the item by click of mouse.

So, I would like the handler about focus of mouse or keyboard, the element name.

Comment: You are probably looking for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa. This would install a hook in the system and whenever there is a related even, your callback function would be called. You could google it to find some examples online.

Comment: As far as the system's concerned keyboard focus is at the window level. Individual windows (like the ListView32 control, which provides the desktop) can provide finer grained focus within themselves when they are the focused window, but the system doesn't know anything about it and certainly doesn't provide a hook to find out when it changes.

Comment: @Harveer alternatively, several of the hooks provided by `SetWindowsHookEx()` can be handled more efficiently and safely using [`SetWinEventHook()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook) instead.

Comment: You'll want to use [WinEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinAuto/winevents-collision169) (as mentioned in the previous comment), and handle the `EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS` [event constant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinAuto/event-constants). Since you posted part of a web page you need to verify, whether your browser provides reliable interface implementations. Google Chrome is notoriously bad at that.

Comment: So, I trying use these handlers, because, I writing a screen reader for windows... Maybe after this information you can have a better idea for what I would like these callback or whatever

Comment: @IInspectable You could show me a example in code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had success with this code.

```
// Global variable.
HWINEVENTHOOK g_hook;

//
// Callback function that handles events.
//
void CALLBACK HandleWinEvent(HWINEVENTHOOK hook, DWORD event, HWND hwnd,
    LONG idObject, LONG idChild,
    DWORD dwEventThread, DWORD dwmsEventTime)
{
    std::cout << "Inside CB" << std::endl;
}

// Initializes COM and sets up the event hook.
void InitializeMSAA()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    g_hook = SetWinEventHook(
        EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS, EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS,  // Range of events (4 to 5).
        NULL,                                          // Handle to DLL.
        HandleWinEvent,                                // The callback.
        0, 0,              // Process and thread IDs of interest (0 = all)
        WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS); // Flags.
}


// Unhooks the event and shuts down COM.
//
void ShutdownMSAA()
{
    UnhookWinEvent(g_hook);
    CoUninitialize();
}


int main()
{
    InitializeMSAA();

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks all for yours reply